# Issue with form validation in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, authentication

i have an issue in validinting my form it's a singup form, i have login and user controller, whene i submit the form it takes me to login page.

Whene i change the default controoler to "user" it validates the form but whene i want to login it's not working. i want to know what is the probleme !

this is the validation form code from the user controller :

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }
    function index()
        {
            //set validation rules
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('prenom', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[teacher.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|md5');

            //validate form input
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                // fails
                $this->load->view('backend/user_registration_view');
            }
```

this is the view :

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <?php $attributes = array("name" => "registrationform");
                echo form_open("user/register", $attributes);?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">First Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your First Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></span>
                </div>
```

this is the ink where i test my app please helpe me solve this issue:

http://prof.skolarie.com (login is the default controller).

I think whene login is set by default override the user controller !

Thanks

Update : The routes file;

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

You can find the code source in this link below :

http://prof.skolarie.com/uploads/myapp.zip

Comment: you are defining rules in index function and posting form data to register function?

Answer (score 0):

Your pages are hard to read, try yo have things as simple as you can, so you can see where you made any mistake, i tried to see where the problem could be, but all i can find is that your forms are pointing to strange links ex the registration form is pointing to :

```
http://prof.skolarie.com/index.php/user/index
```

This link is really missed up, the form should be pointing to a controller that checks the inputs, puts them into the database using a model, then point back to the logging controller

Also it might be either a routing problem, or that you have changed your 404 error view, because visiting any random page on your website, it generates a login form instead of showing a 404 error (ex : i visited : `http://prof.skolarie.com/index.php/random/random/random123` and it kept showing me the login form ), make sure your routes are valid, and that they point to the right controller.

If you keep having this problem, have the right code samples posted, as well as for your routes.

Comment: You can see the code source from this link : http://prof.skolarie.com/uploads/myapp.zip ,
In the route file i have this : 

$route['default_controller'] = 'login';

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

Comment: you are not taking advantage of the MVC arch that codeigniter provides.launching functions from the model is

Comment: Miss clicked enter on the previous comment, as i said your not properly using your codeigniter code, i made some changes on your files, download them here : https://www.mediafire.com/?4ff7c4u1cpxepxm

Comment: Thank you very much for being so helpful but i tried the modification that you sent to me but it did not work,

Comment: I did some modifications and it works for me, i grouped the login and singup controllers in one file and it works now you can try .

Answer (score 0):

You are posting form on `user/register` and i think your validations in `index` function so please make validations on `register` function instead of `index`.

Comment: i have changed the validation form from register function to the inde function to see if this is the problem but it seems not, you can download the code source from this link : http://prof.skolarie.com/uploads/myapp.zip . Thank you